# Symfony2 FOS extend base user from yaml

Tags: symfony, yaml, fosuserbundle

I always use yaml when generating entities.
When installing FOSUserBundle, after generating User entity, I also had to edit my Bundle\Entity\User.php for extending User from FOSUser.
So, is there any way to extend base entity from yaml?

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't extends in YAML beaucause the object inheritance is not a Symfony component, it directly managed by the php core.

See Documentation : http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php